# d3 weighted scale - different bandwidth by domain value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking for the best option in d3 (V4) to create some kind of weighted scale, so the bandwidth of each band will be calculated based on his domain value. If my domain contains the weight of each band, I would like to get the scale respectively.

For example -

Domain = [1,4,5]

Range = [0,100]

the bandwidth for item#1 will be 10, the bandwidth of item#2 will be 40, etc.